# Hiding filename.php in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having troubles with URL hidding, from `http://example.com/products/product.php` to `http://example.com/products/` or `http://example.com/products/product/`.

I have tried this block of code in htaccess, but it seems not to work.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: for more details about that http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html , otherwise I think starkeen answer will fix it

Comment: If you're using PHP anyway, why not hide anything but the domain? Keep the state in `$_SESSION` variables, use `POST` with action `/`  and set up the next page in `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the .php extension, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)redirect  "/file.php" to "/file"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
#2)internally redirect "/file" to "/file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```